# How to create an edit button in React?

Tags: reactjs, button, edit

I am fairly new to React so any help would be appreciated!

What I am trying to do is create an edit button for my code that allows the user to edit the persons birth year, and their home world. I want the text to appear as a text box when the edit button is pressed, so that the user can change it, and then save it somehow. Here is my code:

```
class Card extends Component {

    render() {
      const {imgSrc, cardName, birthYear, onEdit} = this.props;
      return (
        <div className='card'>
          <div className='card-content'>
            <div className='card-name'>{cardName}</div>
                <img src={`http://localhost:3008/${imgSrc}`} alt='profile'/>
              <p>
                  <span>Birthday:</span>
                  <span className='birth-year'>{birthYear}</span>
              </p>
              <p>

                  <span>Homeworld:</span>
                  <span className='home-world'>Earth</span>
                  </p>
                <div align='center'>
                <button>Edit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have an internal `editing` state, based on which the component renders either the input field with the default value as the current value for that field or the `<span>`. It flips to true when you press the edit button. You'll also have to conditionally render an update/save button and update the values when save is clicked. This is the general idea.

```
class Card extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editing: false
    };
    this.newbirthYear = "";
    this.newHomeWorld = "";
  }

  render() {
    const { imgSrc, cardName, birthYear, homeWorld, onEdit } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-content">
          <div className="card-name">{cardName}</div>
          <img src={`http://localhost:3008/${imgSrc}`} alt="profile" />
          <p>
            <span>Birthday:</span>
            {this.state.editing ? (
              <span className="birth-year">{birthYear}</span>
            ) : (
              <input
                type="text"
                defaultValue={birthYear}
                ref={node => {
                  this.newbirthYear = node;
                }}
              />
            )}
          </p>
          <p>
            <span>Homeworld:</span>
            {this.state.editing ? (
              <span className="home-world">{homeWorld}</span>
            ) : (
              <input
                type="text"
                defaultValue={homeWorld}
                ref={node => {
                  this.newHomeWorld = node;
                }}
              />
            )}
          </p>
          <div align="center">
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                this.setState({ editing: true });
              }}
            >
              Edit
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to setState based on the incoming props.  Then in your form you would need to do something like

```
<input type='text' defaultValue={this.state.user.birthday} />
```